# Python: SSL error: tlsv1 alert protocol version

Tags: python, ssl, python-requests

I'm using below code to call api. It was working till yesterday but started giving this exception.

Please let me know solution for this issue.

```
url = "https://%s:9060/ers/config/downloadableacl/%s" % ('ip', dacl_id)

def rest_msg (type, url, params=None, json=None, auth=None, headers=None):
    headers = headers or {
        'Content-Type': "application/json",
        'Accept': "application/json",
    }

    r = requests.request(type,
                         url,
                         auth = auth,
                         headers = headers,
                         params = params,
                         json = json,
                          proxies={'https': None},
                         verify = False)
```

Comment: Bad practice of using type as a variable name, btw what is the error?

Comment: What python version do you use? On what platform/OS do you execute the code?

Comment: It is unknown what exactly worked before (exactly the same code?) and what kind of exception you got. If nothing in the code changed then likely something outside of the code - only nothing is known about this. It might be that the server is not running anymore, is blocked by a firewall, is misconfigured, expects SNI now instead of access as IP etc - impossible to tell based on the provided information.

Comment: @NishantNawarkhede Exception: SSL error: tlsv1 alert protocol version

Comment: @Robert we are using 3.5 python version

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Thank you for the reply. Exception: SSL error: tlsv1 alert protocol version. I got this exception. I didn't add complete code but this snippet communicates with server.